# yum install 404 error

Tags: linux, fedora

Installed hadoop via yum install

But now when I do yum install anything it says

14: HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://vdt.cs.wisc.edu/hadoop/mirrorlists/hadoop-16-x86_64.txt

How do I clear this http://vdt.cs.wisc.edu/hadoop/mirrorlists/hadoop-16-x86_64.txt

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where yum is pulling that URL as I am not sure how you have your Repo's setup?  But you can use

```
yum clean all
```

To clear out the yum cache.  The reason for the 404 is in fact that file does not exist.

Comment: yum clean all does the trick..................................